# How do I get user details in controller of Spring Boot OIDC app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have adapted the code from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect) to call a MitreID OIDC server.

My controller:

```
    public final String home(Principal p) {
    final String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
...
```

returns `null` and is null for all userdetails.

I have also tried:

```
public final String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal OpenIdConnectUserDetails user) {
        final String username = user.getUsername();
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserNameSimple(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        return "username: " + principal.getName();
    }
```

Everything is null but the authentication *is* returning an access and user token.

My security config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenIdConnectFilter myFilter() {

        final OpenIdConnectFilter filter = new OpenIdConnectFilter("/openid_connect_login");
        filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
        .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(myFilter(), OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
        .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/openid_connect_login"))
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","/index*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;

     // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

So why can my controller not access the userdetails?

EDIT: as requested, `OpenIdConnectFilter`:

```
 package org.baeldung.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtHelper;
import org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaVerifier;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

import com.auth0.jwk.Jwk;
import com.auth0.jwk.JwkProvider;
import com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class OpenIdConnectFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    @Value("${oidc.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oidc.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Value("${oidc.jwkUrl}")
    private String jwkUrl;

    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    public OpenIdConnectFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoopAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;
        logger.info("ewd here: b " );
        try {
            accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
        } catch (final OAuth2Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain access token", e);
        }
        try {
            logger.info("ewd access token: " + accessToken);
            final String idToken = accessToken.getAdditionalInformation().get("id_token").toString();
            String kid = JwtHelper.headers(idToken)
                .get("kid");
            final Jwt tokenDecoded = JwtHelper.decodeAndVerify(idToken, verifier(kid));
            final Map<String, String> authInfo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(tokenDecoded.getClaims(), Map.class);
            verifyClaims(authInfo);
            final OpenIdConnectUserDetails user = new OpenIdConnectUserDetails(authInfo, accessToken);
            logger.info("ewd user token: " + tokenDecoded);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain user details from token", e);
        }

    }

    public void verifyClaims(Map claims) {
        int exp = (int) claims.get("exp");
        Date expireDate = new Date(exp * 1000L);
        Date now = new Date();
        if (expireDate.before(now) || !claims.get("iss").equals(issuer) || !claims.get("aud").equals(clientId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid claims");
        }
    }


    private RsaVerifier verifier(String kid) throws Exception {
        JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(jwkUrl));
        Jwk jwk = provider.get(kid);
        return new RsaVerifier((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey());
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate2) {
        restTemplate = restTemplate2;

    }

    private static class NoopAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No authentication should be done with this AuthenticationManager");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you also provide your OpenIdConnectFilter class?

Comment: Thanks. Added it.

Comment: have you had a look in here? https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki/Client-configuration

Comment: I can't see any configured user information Url that spring can use to fill the principle. am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you refer to, Google OpenId Connect is used. This service also returns the extra scope email variable that is read in:

OpenIdConnectUserDetails.class

```
    public OpenIdConnectUserDetails(Map<String, String> userInfo, OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        this.userId = userInfo.get("sub");
        this.username = userInfo.get("email");
        this.token = token;
    }
```

Without knowing the specific configuration of your MitreID OIDC server maybe the openId server is not returning the email variable

Comment: Thanks but it is being returned but it is not visible in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new auth0 user and had the same issue, trying to get some User information in the Spring Controller.  I am able to access the Claims from the token using this code.

```
@GetMapping
public List<Task> getTasks(AuthenticationJsonWebToken authentication) {
    logger.debug("getTasks called.");
    DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(authentication.getToken());
    Map<String, Claim> claims = jwt.getClaims();
    for (Object key: claims.keySet()) {
        logger.debug("key: {}, value: {}", key.toString(),  claims.get(key).asString());
    }

    return taskRepository.findAll();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need username, you can get it from `JwtAuthenticationToken` object as below:

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(JwtAuthenticationToken user) {
        String name = user.getName();
```

If you need some other information from user's profile, you can call your auth server's `/userinfo` endpoint with the access token as below:
**This will fetch info only if you had included `profile` scope in your `authorize` call.**

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(JwtAuthenticationToken user) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer "+user.getToken().getTokenValue());
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> userinfo = template.exchange("https://your-auth-server/default/v1/userinfo", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
        String name = (String) userinfo.getBody().get("given_name");
```

You can retrieve all profile attributes from this response.

Answer (score 0):

For Auth0, I was able to get user information in two ways:

1. First one is using JwtAuthenticationToken directly on the controller as shown below.

```java
@GetMapping("/info")
public void users(JwtAuthenticationToken token) {
    System.out.println(token.getName());
    System.out.println(token.getTokenAttributes().get("name"));
}
```

Here, `token.getName()` prints the user id from auth0 and `token.getTokenAttributes()` returns a map from which we can retrieve any information that we need. For example to print user name, we can use :

```java
token.getTokenAttributes().get("name");
```

2. Casting Authentication object to JwtAuthenticationToken:

```java
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
JwtAuthenticationToken token = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
String username = token.getTokenAttributes().get("name");
```

Comment: need proper formating

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the user or profile related properties that were defined when creating the okta oidc application through the OidcUser class, which can be used with the AuthenticationPrincipal annotation.Follow below steps

```
**My Controller:**

 @GetMapping("/user")
    public User user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
        System.out.println("oidcUser :: " + oidcUser + "\n\n");

        User user = new User();

        System.out.println("Attributes :: " + oidcUser.getAttributes() + "\n\n");       
        user.setFirstName(oidcUser.getAttribute("given_name"));
        user.setLastName(oidcUser.getAttribute("family_name"));
        user.setName(oidcUser.getAttribute("name"));
        user.setPreferred_username(oidcUser.getAttribute("preferred_username"));
        user.setEmail(oidcUser.getAttribute("email"));
        user.setGroups(getGroupsFromCurrentUser());

        System.out.println(user.toString() + "\n\n");
        return  user;
    }
     
    private List<String> getGroupsFromCurrentUser() {
          List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
          Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
          System.out.println("\n\n"+authorities+"\n\n");
          for (GrantedAuthority auth : authorities) {
              groups.add(auth.getAuthority());
          }
          
          System.out.println("\n\n"+"groups :: "+groups+"\n\n");
          return groups;
        }
```