# Extract user from authentication token

Tags: azure-api-management

I have created custom Oauth2 service and configured API to use it according to the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2

Using Developer Portal I see that access token is sent to the API endpoint. However I need to have one more piece of information sent to my endpoint. The access token looks like this:

> {"access_token":"e_Pt_0mEUKfMk7DzN7QDmb4tx6syaMM9d7Ei9UH4y1pYipErNHZFz9dU5ZmdTIvr2R4fD1GxJZY-Bsyt7tIpm7uKFScrrKRAKBVGeU3T7R1WTiBV3WglPK1OHZgOSpIY","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,**"user":"T81lum-5p6QvDR7l6hv7lfE52bAbA2ylWBnv9CZEzNb0B"**}"

I need to extract the user property of the token and send it to API endpoint. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Is the Authorization header with a Bearer token available? This would allow you to dissect the token and maybe extract the user claim or attribute.

Comment: I tested it with an AAD application registration and get a Authorization header with a Bearer token passed. Is the user information you require contained also in the token? Then I could provide policy expression code to extract this information from the token.

Comment: What OP is asking, He wishes to send one more property to API gateway endpoint from developer portal which he received from OAuth 2.0 endpoint aside from Access Token? Right now he is only getting Access token, but there is one more property available in response from his service. He wants to send that to API endpoint as well. Alex correct if me I'm wrong here?

Comment: @AmeyVaidya You are correct. I'm receiving the bearer value but I also need to receive the user value which is contained within the token.

Comment: @KaiWalter I read your responses also and think I understand what you mean. Do you mean that bearer token can contain user information also? If so, I'm not sure if it does and how I would go about extracting it. As you can see in the example of the OP, I get the access_token and user in the final step of OAuth2 authentication process.

Comment: @AlexS - just capture the Authorization header value in developer portal trace, remove "Bearer " and put it into jwt.ms or jwt.io to check the contents of the Bearer token.

Comment: @KaiWalter Thank you again. The bearer token is not a JWT token in my case. It does not work on jwt.ms

Comment: @AlexS in what section of the trace do you see the token in the developer portal? Maybe I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Just share an idea about this. the user name is encoded in the bear token that can be parsed with JWT. You can add policy in <inbound> where you parse token and save user name to header then pass to your backend. the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) already provided the JWT parser

```
Jwt jwt = AsJwt(put_your_token_in_here)
String userName = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("name")
```

see [JWT token](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token).

Comment: Thank you for the idea and the effort. The token provided in the original example is not in JWT format and therefore cannot be decoded. Please also see comments in the original post.

Comment: Instead of decoding token, Did you try to use context.User in api management policy? you can save user into the header and pass to your backend point. in my project, i use OpenID, so i can decode token as JWT.

Comment: Do you mean that the value of the "user" property in access token will be transferred to Content.User?

Comment: The user relates to the subscriber of the product or API.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON and extract the user id, but it's going to be dependent on the language you're using.

In Node.JS, it's pretty straightforward (here assuming the auth blob is a string, and not yet parsed):

```
let userid = JSON.parse( auth_blob ).user;
```

In Java using GSON:

```java
JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse( auth_blob );
JsonElement userElement = jsonTree.get("user");
String user = userElement.getAsString();
```

and so on... searching for "parse JSON" and your language of choice will help you out there.

There's a short tutorial for how to embed a json extract in Azure here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/api-management/policies/cache-response?toc=api-management/toc.json

```
<!-- Extract a JSON object containing lat/long from the response and serialize it into a variable. -->
<set-variable name="latlong" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["response="""]).Body.As<JObject>
    ()["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"].ToString())"/>
```

So, I suppose that you could do the same thing for your auth blob:

```
<set-variable name="user" value="@((auth_blob).Body.As<JObject>
    ()["user"].ToString())"/>
```

Please edit if this is incorrect - I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time and responding. Reagrding "You can parse the JSON and extract the user id, but it's going to be dependent on the language you're using.". You are assuming that I have access to JSON of the auth token, but I do not. This is the core of the issue. API Management handles the auth token exchange and therefore I do not know how to access that value. Once I have the JSON value I can certainly parse it as you have suggested. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, that's an issue.  You'll have to take that up with the developers of the framework you're using.  If the framework doesn't tell you, you can't be expected to know.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve user details from auth code. You can do it using an access token.
Please refer to similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224482/7169325)